# How do you mix JMeter command line args with Gui args?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run a single recording in various different ways without copying the recorded pages.

I have created two [Property File Readers](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/) that look for:

```
C:\performance\jmeter\users_${__P(ttype)}.properties
```

and

```
C:\performance\jmeter\${__P(env)}_${__P(region)}.properties
```

where the ${__P(xxx)} variables are passed on the command line as so:

```
-Jregion=UK -Jenv=dev -Jttype=isolated
```

These property files load the following variables (for example):

```
- usercount=25
- duration=1800
- host.name=server1
- host.port=8546
```

These are used in the HTTP Request Defaults:

```
${__P(host.name)}
${__P(host.port)}
```

and Thread Group:

```
${__P(duration)}
${__P(usercount)}
```

This works fine. However, if I want to run the same test in the Gui for a single thread (to check it works), these variables are not populated and the test fails.

I can create a User Defined Variable element but these have the format

```
${xxx}
```

so cannot be used interchangeably.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do here, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Option 1: you can pass the same parameters via '-J` arguments as JMeter in the GUI mode respects them as well
- Option 2: you can specify your properties values in *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder) like

  ```
  usercount=25
  duration=1800
  etc.
  ```

The properties values passed over the command-line will override those, which are specified in the *user.properties*

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on using JMeter properties

---

By the way, you ain't gonna need this Property File Readers, there is a possibility to add extra properties files in JMeter via [`-q` command line argument.](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

> **-q, --addprop**
>
> additional JMeter property file(s)

Answer (score 1):

Discovered another way to resolve this issue.

The __P() function can take a second argument that acts as the default if the first value isn't resolved.
So

```
${__P(host.name)}
${__P(host.port)}
```

become

```
${__P(host.name,server1)}
${__P(host.port,1234)}
```

This works as well.